# How do I extract data from related entities in Core Data correctly?

Tags: core-data, swift4

There are two entities: NameList (with the name attribute) and ListArray (with the array attribute). They are linked by a to - many relationship:
[image]

I want to display in the first Table view as a table saved name and when you select some name go to SecondTableView where the data from ListArray will be displayed. And also be able to delete and edit them. What happens: I put both tables, but I can't edit anything on the second.

```
class FirstTableView: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

var fetchResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NameList>!
var fetchResultControllerArray: NSFetchedResultsController<ListArray>!

var toDoItems: [NameList] = []
var toDoArray: [ListArray] = []


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.coreDataStack.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NameList> = NameList.fetchRequest()
    let fetchRequesrArr: NSFetchRequest<ListArray> = ListArray.fetchRequest()

    do {
        toDoItems = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        toDoArray = try context.fetch(fetchRequesrArr)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
         }

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return toDoItems.count

}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    let nameList = toDoItems[(indexPath.row)]
    cell.textLabel?.text = nameList.name


    return cell
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).coreDataStack.persistentContainer.viewContext

    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let task = toDoItems[indexPath.row]
        let array = toDoArray[indexPath.row]
        context.delete(task)
        context.delete(array)
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        do {
            toDoItems = try context.fetch(NameList.fetchRequest())

            tableView.reloadData()
            print(toDoArray.count)
        } catch {
            print("Fetching Failed")
        }
    }
    print("del")
    //tableView.reloadData()
}

 // MARK: - Fetched Results Controller Delegate
func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}


func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

    switch type {
    case .insert: guard let indexPath = newIndexPath else { break }
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    case .delete: guard let indexPath = indexPath else { break }
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    case .update: guard let indexPath = indexPath else { break }
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    default:
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    toDoItems = controller.fetchedObjects as! [NameList]
    toDoArray = controller.fetchedObjects as! [ListArray]

}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.reloadData()
    tableView.endUpdates()

}

 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

    guard let selectedRow = indexPath?.row else { return }

    let selectedList = toDoArray[selectedRow]

    let destinationVC = segue.destination as? SecondTableView

    destinationVC?.readyList = selectedList.array as! [NSObject]
}
}
```

I will lahore for help in the decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code but the main one is that you're working with both entities in parallel when instead you should get your array of ListArray entities from the NameList that is selected. What you do when you need them is something like

```
let listArrayArray = selectedNameList.arrayItems
```

Off-topic: I would recommend against using words like Array in your entity name or anything in plural form since the name of the Entity should describe one object. ListItem could for instance be a better suggestion.

So no need to fetch ListArray objects and the code for delete is just plain wrong.

Looking at the code I suggest the following changes to FirstTableView:

1. Delete the toDoArray property and any code related to it.
2. Handle add, edit and delete of ListArray in SecondTableView
3. Change content of prepare(for segue...) as below

New prepare:

```
let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
guard let selectedRow = indexPath?.row else { return }

let selectedList = toDoItems[selectedRow]

let destinationVC = segue.destination as? SecondTableView

destinationVC?.readyList = selectedList.arrayItems
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tried to do as you advised, but the function prepare (for segue...) sends an empty array and I don't understand how to display data in SecondTableView

Comment: I saw that the last row in prepare(for segue...) was incorrect and fixed it

Comment: The console displays an error:  Optional(Relationship 'arrayItems' fault on managed object (0x60000028ad70) <NameList: 0x60000028ad70> (entity: NameList; id: 0xd000000000280000 <x-coredata://B2FEEDEA-B189-441A-ACE6-21E2758CD5DF/NameList/p10> ; data: {
    arrayItems = "<relationship fault: 0x60400047ca80 'arrayItems'>";
    date = "2018-04-16 08:39:26 +0000";
    name = 2;
}))

Comment: It looks like you have defined your relationship as optional so you will have to check for nil.